# A function that can return an object or a primitive type: is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, casting, return-value, objective-c-runtime

NOTE: the beginning of this question is similar (the first part is the same) as this one: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115237/swizzling-a-method-with-variable-arguments-and-forward-the-message-bad-access)
However, the final question is completely different.

I'm implementing a "Code Injector Class", that through method swizzling can give you the possibility to do something like this:

```
FLCodeInjector *injector = [FLCodeInjector injectorForClass:[self class]];
[injector injectCodeBeforeSelector:@selector(aSelector:) code:^{
    NSLog(@"This code should be injected");
}];
```

`aSelector` can be a method with variable number of arguments, and variable return type. Arguments / and return type can be objects or primitive type.

First, I attach the code of `injectCodeBeforeSelector:` to let you understand what I'm doing (I removed not interesting parts of the code):

```
- (void)injectCodeBeforeSelector:(SEL)method code:(void (^)())completionBlock
{

    NSString *selector = NSStringFromSelector(method);

    [self.dictionaryOfBlocks setObject:completionBlock forKey:selector];

    NSString *swizzleSelector = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SWZ%@", selector];

    //NSMethodSignature *signature = [self.mainClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:method];

    // add a new method to the swizzled class
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self.mainClass, NSSelectorFromString(selector));
    const char *encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod);


    [self addSelector:NSSelectorFromString(swizzleSelector) toClass:self.mainClass originalSelector:method methodTypeEncoding:encoding];
    SwizzleMe(self.mainClass, NSSelectorFromString(selector), NSSelectorFromString(swizzleSelector));

}

    -(void)addSelector:(SEL)selector toClass:(Class)aClass originalSelector:(SEL)originalSel methodTypeEncoding:(const char *)encoding
{

    //NSMethodSignature *signature = [aClass methodSignatureForSelector:originalSel];
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:encoding];
    const char *type = [signature methodReturnType];
    IMP implementation = (IMP)intGenericFunction;


    if (strcmp(@encode(id), type) == 0) {
        // the argument is an object
        implementation = objectGenericFunction;
    }
    else if (strcmp(@encode(int), type) == 0)
    {
        // the argument is an int
        implementation = (IMP)intGenericFunction;
    }
    else if (strcmp(@encode(long), type) == 0)
    {
        // the argument is a long
        implementation = (IMP)longGenericFunction;

    }
    else if (strcmp(@encode(double), type) == 0)
    {
        // the argument is double
        implementation = (IMP)doubleGenericFunction;
    }
    else if (strcmp(@encode(float), type) == 0)
    {
        // the argument is float
        implementation = (IMP)floatGenericFunction;
    }
    else
    {
        // the argument is char or others
        implementation = (IMP)intGenericFunction;
    }



    class_addMethod(aClass,
                    selector,
                    implementation, encoding);
}
```

What is happening here? Basically, basing on the expected return type of the original selector, I add a new method to the object with the correct return type, then apply the swizzle.

All is working correctly, but I'd like to know if it's possible to "compact" the following code (some syntax that I don't know or something I'm missing), because for each return type I have a function that is almost identical to the others, only the returned type is different.
I attach two of them as an example:

```
int intGenericFunction(id self, SEL cmd, ...) {

    FLCodeInjector *injector = [FLCodeInjector injectorForClass:[self class]];
    [injector executeBlockForSelector:cmd];


    va_list arguments, copiedArguments;
    va_start ( arguments, cmd );
    va_copy(copiedArguments, arguments);
    va_end(arguments);

    void * returnValue = getReturnValue(self, cmd, copiedArguments);

    int returnedInt = *(int *)returnValue;
    return returnedInt;
}

double doubleGenericFunction(id self, SEL cmd, ...) {

    FLCodeInjector *injector = [FLCodeInjector injectorForClass:[self class]];
    [injector executeBlockForSelector:cmd];


    va_list arguments, copiedArguments;
    va_start ( arguments, cmd );
    va_copy(copiedArguments, arguments);
    va_end(arguments);

    void * returnValue = getReturnValue(self, cmd, copiedArguments);

    double returnedDouble = *(double *)returnValue;
    return returnedDouble;
}
```

As you can see, the functions are almost identical, the only different is the CAST before the return, and the return type of the function.

I'm implementing it in the correct way, or there are more efficient way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Neat-o! I'm going to have to take a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that you'll need to write a different IMP for each return type, at least unless you drop down to assembly to do the dispatch, the way `objc_msgSend` does. (Even that function requires a couple different type variants, though.) However, if the difference truly is just a couple of type names, you may be able to define a macro that reduces the boilerplate:

```
// This macro syntax is off the top of my head; it may not be correct.
#define GENERIC_FUNCTION_FOR_TYPE(type) type type##GenericFunction(id self, SEL cmd, ...) { \
    ...other lines omitted... \
    type returnedValue = *(type *)returnValue; \
    return returnedValue; \
}

GENERIC_FUNCTION_FOR_TYPE(int)
GENERIC_FUNCTION_FOR_TYPE(double)
...etc...
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer, but a note to the OP: be prepared for some annoyingly tricky debugging sessions if you elect use macros this way, especially in the context of something as obscure as generically swizzled methods. That's not going to be easy to maintain. I'm not saying it's not worth it, because you haven't specified WHY you want to do this, but yeesh! Hopefully this is for something like enhanced unit testing capabilities as opposed to production code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The main reason behind this question is that I don't know very well what is done "behind the scene" :-) so the main goal was, first, to have a confirm that my approach was right, and then a shortcut (like the macro). I'll try it and then decide if use the macro or not. The class I'm creating is meant mainly for debug/testing purpose and should not be used in production code :-) it will be soon available on GitHub. Thanks again

Comment: If anyone is interested, here the github link for the very first version of the class: [link](https://github.com/lombax85/FLCodeInjector)